# Modifying values of array `a` using values in array `m` to create array 'c'

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider array `a` which, in this example, has 5 rows and 6 columns.
Each row holds values 0 to 5.
The 30 elements of `a` make up 15 pairings using the following rule: **If column p of a row holds value q,  then column q of that row holds value p**.  To avoid duplication of pairings, we consider only the pairings where p > q.

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4],
              [2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 3],
              [3, 5, 4, 0, 2, 1],
              [4, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2],
              [5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0]])
```

Here are some of the 15 pairings, named by the column indices:
In row 0, pairing `(0,1)` holds values `(1,0)`,  pairing `(2,3)` holds values `(3,2)`, and pairing `(4,5)` holds values `(5,4)`.
... etc ...
In row 4, pairing `(0,5)` holds values `(5,0)`,  pairing `(1,2)` holds values `(2,1)`, and pairing `(3,4)` holds values `(4,3)`.

Now, consider array `m`.

```
m = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5], 

              [6, 4,-2, 5, 0,-1, 1, 4,-7,-8,-7, 3,-4, 1, 0],
              [3,-8, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 5, 5, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0]])
```

The  1st two rows of `m` show the 15 pairings `(0,1), (0,2), ... (0,5), (1,2), ... (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)`.
The last two rows of `m` show values that, **for each pairing, must be added to the corresponding elements of** `a`.

So,  to `a` pairing `(0, 1)`, we add `(6, 3)` to the existing values `(1, 0)` to get values `(7, 3)`
and, to `a` pairing `(0, 2)`, we add `(4,-8)` to the existing values `(2, 0)` to get values `(6,-8)`.

The final outcome would look like:

```
c = np.array([[7, 3,-5, 7, 5, 4],
              [6, 8,-8, 6, 7, 4],
              [1,-2,-3, 1, 2, 6],
              [9, 4, 8, 2, 2, 4],
              [5, 1, 4, 0, 6, 1]])
```

QUESTION:  How can the values in `m` be uesd to modify the values in `a` to produce `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is a simpler way, since my solution is O(nmp), (n×m being the size of matrix `a` and `p` the number of columns in matrix `M`.

When it should be possible to have a O(np) solution (for each column in matrix `m`, we access matching columns of matrix `a`, and search for the row).

But at least it is "vectorized"; it uses no python `for` loop

```py
col=np.arange(a.shape[1])
mask=(m[0][:,None,None]==col[None,None,:]) & (m[1][:,None,None]==a)
```

Creates a 3d boolean mask. Axis 0 is for each column of `m`. And axis 1 and 2 are rows and columns of `a`.
A position `k,i,j` in that mask is True if `m[1,k]` is equal to `a[i,j]` and `j` (aka `col[k,i,j]`) is equal to `m[0,k]`.
So a `True` in that mask at position `k,i,j` means that at position `i`,`j` of `a`, there is a value that is equal to `m[0,k]`

We need to add `m[2,k]` to that `[i,j]` position in `a`. And in the same `row` `i`, but column `m[1,k]` to add `m[3,k]`.

Hence the rest

```py
k,i,j=np.where(mask) 
a[i,j] += m[2]
a[i, m[1,k]] += m[3]
```

Of course, you need to create a copy of `a` before if you want to keep original `a` intact

So the matching function

```
def withoutFor(a,m):
    col=np.arange(a.shape[1])
    k,i,j=np.where((m[0][:,None,None]==col[None,None,:]) & (m[1][:,None,None]==a))
    c=a.copy()
    c[i,j] += m[2]
    c[i, m[1,k]] += m[3]
    return c
```

### A non-vectorized version

Just to stress out my original point (it is not optimal, complexity-wise) here is how it could be done with a `for` loop

```py
def withFor(a,m):
    c=a.copy()
    for v in m.T:
        row=np.where(a[:,v[0]]==v[1])[0][0]
        c[row,v[0]] += v[2]
        c[row,v[1]] += v[3]
    return c
```

Complexity is one order of magnitude lower. Still, it is 3 times slower with your example. It might change with bigger examples

## Edit: both way

Actually, I just needed to write the `for loop` version to realize that this version can be "vectorized" too. So we can have our cake and eat it. Namely having a O(np) version that don't use for loop

```py
def bothWay(a,m):
    row=np.where((a[:, m[0,:]]==m[1,:]).T)[1] 
    c=a.copy()
    c[row, m[0]] += m[2]
    c[row, m[1]] += m[3]
    return c
```

Which, even on your small example, is already faster than the 2 other methods. And should win even more on longer run.

`a[:, m[0,:]]` is a 5×15 matrix, whose columns are the one given in the first row of `m` (that is a 5×15 matrix whose element `i,j` is element `i,m[0,j]` of matrix `a`)

So `(a[:, m[0,:]]==m[1,:])` is a 5×15 boolean matrix whose elements at position `i,j` is True iff element i,m[0,j] of matrix `a` is equal to value in row 1, column j of `m`. In other words. In other words, in each j=0 to 14 columns, you have `True` at row position where in column `m[0,j]` you can find value in `m[1,j]`.

For example, column 7 of this boolean matrix contains `True` at row 1 (second row), because in column 1 of matrix `a` (1 being what we find at 1st row of column 7 of `m`) you find a 4 (what is at 2nd row of column 7 of `m`) in row 1.

So, that matrix has as many column as `m`. And each column contains one, and only one `True`. Matching row where, in matrix `a`, I can find value in 2nd row of `m` in column indicated in 1st row of `m`.

By transposing that boolean matrix, I get a 15×5 boolean matrix. Which ensure, because of order in which `np.where` works, that I'll get the 15 position.

Therefore `np.where((a[:, m[0,:]]==m[1,:]).T)[1]` are the 15 rows I need to know. (`...[0]` are just the numbers 0 to 14)
For each column of `m`, this give me the row number of `a` where I can find value in 2nd row of `m` at column indicated in first row of `m`.

So, `a[row]` are 15 the 15 rows I need to alter, for each 15 columns of `m`.
`a[row, m[0]]` are the 15 values, found in a in those rows, columns `m[0]`. I need to add to those 15 values the 15 values I find in `m[2]`. Likewise `a[row, m[1]]` are the 15 values, in the matching column, same rows. To which I need to add the 15 values I find in the 4th row of `m`.

Comment: Thanks chrsig.   Your solution works perfectly, and I appreciate the detailed yet exceptionally clear explanations.  Really instructive.